# How can I check content type file uploaded in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check what the type of a file is that was uploded to my site.
I have a `<input type="file">` tag in my HTML that the user can use to upload.
Is there any way to check what the type of the file is witout its extension?

For example:

```
user uploads `aFile.txt`
```

Application output:

```
uploaded file is mp3
```

I do not want to check the file extension. I want to check the actual content of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `python-magic` library

```
>>> import magic
>>> magic.from_file("testdata/test.pdf")
'PDF document, version 1.2'
# recommend using at least the first 2048 bytes, as less can produce incorrect identification
>>> magic.from_buffer(open("testdata/test.pdf").read(2048)) 
'PDF document, version 1.2'
>>> magic.from_file("testdata/test.pdf", mime=True)
'application/pdf'
```

Comment: i try this , only return `data`  as output, using windows

Comment: @NozarSafari Could you elaborate?

Comment: first install `python-magic` and after import get this error `Exception Value:failed to find libmagic. Check your installation` after some search uninstall `python-magic` and reinstall with this command `pip install python-magic-bin==0.4.14`. now all files are `data`

Comment: Follow this https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic#installation

Comment: `You'll need DLLs for libmagic. @julian-r has uploaded a version of this project that includes binaries to PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic-bin/0.4.14
`  thats exactly what i do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `re` module :

```
import re
#Place this in a loop if required to open multiple files.
with open('aFile.txt') as f :
    match = re.findall('<input type="file">',f.read())
    if match :
        print('Do your stuff')
```